# Regular Expressions in ubuntu command line

Tags: regex, linux

Hello I have a fairly simple question I want to search for only the last '1+1' before the = sign from this statement

```
1+1+1+1+1+1=6
```

I have tried the grep statement

```
`grep '.+' 'text.txt'`
```

it returns

```
1+1+1+1+1+
```

as it highlights all of the + symbols. I believe I need to create a min range such as:
`grep '.+{4,}' 'text.txt'` This does not work, can anyone explain why? A solution with explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't grep return the whole line when it finds the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last `+`-expression you could use `grep -o` and pipe that into `tail -1`:

```
grep -o '[0-9]+[0-9]' <<< '1+1+1+1+2+1=6' | tail -1
```

This regex matches a number (between 0 and 9) `[0-9]`, followed by a literal `+` sign, followed by a number again. That will match more than one part of your expression string. The `-o` option prints each match on a separate line, and the `tail` selects the last one of these lines.

If you have the expression in a file `text.txt`, just use:

```
grep -o '[0-9]+[0-9]' text.txt | tail -1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but i really dont understand how it does it. Why 0-9 + 0-9? Edit- I see you edited your comment to explain it. Cheers!

Comment: @user3423572 I'll add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a metacharacter that means "1 or more of the previous match".  When you say `.+` you're saying "any character, and then 1 or more of any character."

If you want to search for a literal metacharacter, you must escape it with a backslash.

```
grep '.\+' text.txt
```

Comment: This may vary by system and grep-family you're using - `+` is a _normal_ character for basic regular expressions, _unless_ it is escaped to become a metacharacter = `grep` == `grep -G` 'a+' finds literal `a+` but grep 'a\+' finds one or more `a` in a sequence; while it's opposite for `egrep` == `grep -E` 'a+' the `+` is already a metacharacter, so grep -E 'a+' finds one or more `a` but grep -E 'a\+' escapes the meta `+` and matches literal `a+` — based on `man 1 grep` for "**BSD** General Commands" on OS X. An online page for man 1 grep on Linux tells me it's the same, but I haven't tested.